cryptsetup - luks header
i will create some write once read many files.
i need only one key for open the file and for me, there is no reason to change in the future the key.
the header will stored on a different place, and goes not out of my safe house, but the date does.
i will have a minimum header size, how to do this?
cryptsetup is version 2.7.5
should i use luksFormat --type luks1 to get a 2MiB header?
or what does --luks2-metadata-size and --luks2-keyslots-size do?
how to understand these both options?

This is basically the same question asked third time with more details added (first and second question). Maybe instead asking again update one of your previous questions or ask for clarification in the comments if the answer doesn't fully cover your use case?
